# Unable to run Docker commands without sudo user in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, sudo, privileges

I am trying to run Docker commands without sudo user, but they are giving me below error:

I following the steps provided online:
Created the docker group --> `sudo groupadd docker`

Add user to the docker group  --> `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`

restarted VM --> `newgrp docker`

`sudo setfacl -m user:$USER:rw /var/run/docker.sock`

restarted docker:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

I also tried modifying the visudo file and added my user privileges as below:

```
sudo visudo
anand   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
anand ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I even tried changing the owner of my `/var/run/docker.sock` file to my user. It was with root initially

`srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Aug  2 12:37 /var/run/docker.sock`

I changed owner to below:

```
srw-rw---- 1 anand anand 0 Aug  2 12:37 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Finally none of the options seem to work. Kindly suggest some options to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you please specify what error you are getting?

Comment: The "below error" seems to be missing from the question.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check if your user (or user that you want to use with docker) is in docker group. For that, just run this command:

```
id -nG
```

If it says that user is in the docker group, then try again running this command if you want to add an active user:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
```

or run this if you want to add some other user:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker other_username
```

After you add a user to the group, you need to logout and then login again to apply new group changes.

Comment: I already tried these commands. My user 'anand' has been added in the group and it is still giving this error after docker restart as well.     anand@anand-ThinkPad-P51:~$ id -nG
anand adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by changing the owner and group of /var/run/docker.sock file as sudo chown anand:docker /var/run/docker.sock. I am now able to run docker commands without sudo also.